# UILabel in self-sizing UITableView Cell calculate height randomly

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an issue with the self-sizing cell in UITableView in Swift, iOS 15.

## I want to create a cell like here:

[image: Expected cell]

And it works fine when the view renders 80% of the cells.
But sometimes I have something like this. It''s how it looks in view debugger:

[image: Cell with issue in view of debugger]

As you can see, in a few cells, the height for UILabel (**nameLabel in my code, which is below**), is much what the view need. I want to use self-sizing cells to support accessibility, but in this case, some cells take up more space than they need. **What is more, when I scroll down and get back to the top, when cells rerender by UI some cells got fixed**.

Also, view debugger shows me the error "Scrollable content size is ambigous for UITableView".

## What I tried to do:

I tried to transfer the code below to UIStackView, I mean nameLabel and teamLabel, but the problem with the height of teamLabel still occurs. I have no idea how to fix this. I tried using .setContentHuggingPriority, but without much effect.

The data I use is downloaded in memory before opening the view, so there is certainly no situation where the view is unable to calculate what size it should be.

When I remove teamLabel, the height of nameLabel looks correct. Despite this, the "purple" error in the debugger still occurs. I checked all the view constraints and each side of the cell has references to the elements. Generally, the cell displays correctly, also with a larger font, if I change the accessibility, but I don't know how to fix the problem with this one UILabel.

I would be very grateful for any tips. I have absolutely no idea how to make it work properly. **What is important, code about hyphenation change nothing - i still have issue without it. I tried add "tableview.estimatedHeightRow" but without expected effect**

## **My custom cell code:**

```
import UIKit

class RaceResultCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "RaceResultDetailsCell"
    
    private let flagImage = FlagImageView(frame: .zero)
    
    private let positionLabel = CellTextLabel(fontStyle: .subheadline, fontWeight: .regular, textColor: .UI.secondaryText, textAlignment: .center)
    private let nameLabel = CellTextLabel(fontStyle: .body, fontWeight: .semibold, textColor: .UI.primaryText)
    
    private let teamLabel = CellTextLabel(fontStyle: .subheadline, fontWeight: .light, textColor: .UI.secondaryText)
    
    private let statusLabel = CellTextLabel(fontStyle: .subheadline, fontWeight: .regular, textColor: .UI.primaryText, textAlignment: .right)
    private let pointsLabel = CellTextLabel(fontStyle: .subheadline, fontWeight: .regular, textColor: .UI.secondaryText, textAlignment: .center)
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
        setupUI()
    }

    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(with model: RaceResultDataModel) {
        positionLabel.text = model.position
        nameLabel.text = "\(model.driver.name) \(model.driver.surname)"
        pointsLabel.text = model.points
        teamLabel.text = model.constructor.name
        statusLabel.text = model.time?.time ?? model.status
        
        flagImage.image = CountryFlagProvider.shared.nationalityFlag(for: model.driver.nationality)
        
        setupHyphenation(for: nameLabel)
        setupHyphenation(for: teamLabel)
        setupHyphenation(for: statusLabel)
    }
    
    private func setupHyphenation(for label: UILabel) {
         label.numberOfLines = 0
         label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
         label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
         label.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
         if let text = label.text {
             let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
             paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1
             let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text,
                                                       attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
             label.attributedText = attributedString
         }
     }

    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(positionLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(flagImage)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(teamLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(statusLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(pointsLabel)

        positionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(6)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(28)
        }
        
        flagImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(positionLabel.snp.trailing).offset(12)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 28, height: 24))

        }
        
        nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
            make.leading.equalTo(flagImage.snp.trailing).offset(12)
            make.trailing.lessThanOrEqualTo(statusLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
        }
                
        
        teamLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(6)
            make.leading.equalTo(flagImage.snp.trailing).offset(12)
            make.trailing.lessThanOrEqualTo(statusLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-12)
        }
        
        statusLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalTo(pointsLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
            make.top.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.top)
            make.bottom.equalTo(teamLabel.snp.bottom)
            make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(50)

        }
        
        pointsLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-6)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(28)
        }       
//        
//    
//        nameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh + 1, for: .vertical)
//        teamLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh + 2, for: .vertical)
//        
//        nameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh + 1, for: .vertical)

    }
}
```

## UILabel which i use:

```
import UIKit

class CellTextLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    convenience init(fontStyle: UIFont.TextStyle, fontWeight: UIFont.Weight, textColor: UIColor!, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment? = nil) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontStyle).pointSize, weight: fontWeight)
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.textAlignment = textAlignment ?? .natural
    }

    private func configure() {
        adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        numberOfLines = 0
        sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

## UITableView setup:

```
 private func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.UI.background
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.register(RaceResultCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: RaceResultCell.identifier)
        tableView.isHidden = false
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        tableView.addSubview(tableViewHeader)
        tableViewHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 50)
        tableViewHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.UI.background
        tableView.tableHeaderView = tableViewHeader

        tableViewHeader.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
            make.height.equalTo(50)
        }
        
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top)
            make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
    }


/// HEIGHT & CELL SETUP IN EXTENSION:

extension ResultsDetailsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // count setup...
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RaceResultCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? RaceResultCell else {
            fatalError("Custom cell error")
        }
        
        let resultData = raceResult.results[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: resultData)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForRowAt _: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to override prepareForReuse method and remove all views from super view and their constraints as well

Comment: Unfortunately, the height of the nameLabel calculated by the cell is still sometimes too high. It always happens vertically :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* the issue lies with the multiple usage of `greaterThanOrEqualTo` on the label width constraints, and auto-layout is having trouble evaluating the Heights of the multi-line labels, because their Widths are changing as the layout is begin evaluated.

Try this:

```
    positionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(6)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(28)
    }
    
    flagImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalTo(positionLabel.snp.trailing).offset(12)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 28, height: 24))
    }
    
    nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
        make.leading.equalTo(flagImage.snp.trailing).offset(12)
        make.trailing.equalTo(statusLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
    }
    
    
    teamLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(6)
        make.leading.equalTo(flagImage.snp.trailing).offset(12)
        make.trailing.equalTo(statusLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-12)
    }
    
    statusLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalTo(pointsLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12)
        make.top.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.top)
        make.bottom.equalTo(teamLabel.snp.bottom)
        make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(50)
    }
    
    pointsLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-6)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(28)
    }

    // add these constraints to help auto-layout manage the labels
    var c: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    c = positionLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0)
    c.priority = .defaultHigh
    c.isActive = true
    
    c = statusLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
    c.priority = .defaultHigh
    c.isActive = true
    
    c = pointsLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0)
    c.priority = .defaultHigh
    c.isActive = true
```

We are effectively giving auto-layout *hints* at the variable width `positionLabel` and `statusLabel` and `pointsLabel` labels.

We've also changed `nameLabel` and `teamLabel` trailing constraints from `lessThanOrEqualTo` to `equalTo`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really very powerful what you wrote. I managed to implement a view in UIStackView with different design before your answer and actually removed the "greaterThan" restrictions there, but I still had full opportunities to implement the view shown in the screenshot.

Really thanks again , I've spent many hours on this over the last two days and now I fully understand to pay attention to implementing restrictions this way in the future.